# Changing a word in a class using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a site that need to have certain words changed. The problem is the HTML etc is not controlled by myself. e.g. I can not edit the html. However, I can append extra code to the end.

The code I need to change is the wording "CHANGE ME" in:

```
<div class="price">
 <a class="button" ng-click="commands.order.execute()" 
    ng-class="(!session.hidePrice &amp;&amp; project.project.requiredCalculation) ? 'refreshing' : ''">
     <span class="icon mdi mdi-cart" ng-class="::$root.icons.basket"></span>
     <currency value="project.project.total.total"
      class="price-total ng-isolate-scope ng-hide" 
      ng-show="!session.hidePrice &amp;&amp; project.project.pricing">
    <span class="currency ng-binding">
     <span ng-class="left" class="ng-binding currency-sign-left">£</span>
     1,089.02<span ng-class="right" class="ng-binding ng-hide">£</span>
    </span>
   </currency>

  <span ng-show="session.hidePrice || !project.project.pricing" class="ng-binding">
   CHANGE ME
  </span>
 </a>
</div>
```

I can change the whole class using:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var myClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("price");

for (var i = 0; i < myClasses.length; i++) {
  myClasses[i].innerHTML = "new content";
  }
</script>
```

Problem is, this removes all the coding and replaces with "new content". What I need to do is keep the content the same but replace the wording "CHANGE ME" with something else.

p.s. ideally I want to say something like Change the wording "CHANGE ME" if it is in the class "price" and the class="ng-binding" (or another identifier, don't know if you can use "ng-show" to identify??)

If possible, please include a fiddle

p.s. needs to be onload so no buttons etc (so no user input needed)

Comment: What do you mean with "Changing a word in a class"? Does class mean a name in attribute "class"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean a word that is in the class.

Comment: @James `a word that is in the element with given class name` ?

Comment: e.g. <div class="price">keep keep CHANGE ME keep keep</div>

Comment: @James See the answer from Suresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot change the Angular code, you can use a selector.

```css
div.price > a.button span:nth-child(3)
```

```js
document.querySelector('div.price > a.button span:nth-child(3)').innerHTML = 'Hello World!';
```

```html
<div class="price">
  <a class="button" ng-click="commands.order.execute()" ng-class="(!session.hidePrice &amp;&amp; project.project.requiredCalculation) ? 'refreshing' : ''">
    <span class="icon mdi mdi-cart" ng-class="::$root.icons.basket"></span>
    <currency value="project.project.total.total" class="price-total ng-isolate-scope ng-hide" ng-show="!session.hidePrice &amp;&amp; project.project.pricing">
      <span class="currency ng-binding">
        <span ng-class="left" class="ng-binding currency-sign-left">£</span>
        1,089.02
        <span ng-class="right" class="ng-binding ng-hide">£</span>
      </span>
    </currency>
    <span ng-show="session.hidePrice || !project.project.pricing" class="ng-binding">
        CHANGE ME
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

You can write a function to loop over all matching elements and either replace some or all of the content.

```js
setContent('div.price > a.button > span', 'CHANGE ME', 'Hello World!', false);

function setContent(selector, pattern, text, replaceContent) {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    var el = els[i];
    if (replaceContent) {
      el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(pattern, text);
    } else {
      if ((pattern instanceof RegExp && el.innerHTML.match(pattern)) ||
          (typeof pattern === 'string' && el.innerHTML.trim() === pattern)) {
        el.innerHTML = text;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="price">
  <a class="button" ng-click="commands.order.execute()" ng-class="(!session.hidePrice &amp;&amp; project.project.requiredCalculation) ? 'refreshing' : ''">
    <span class="icon mdi mdi-cart" ng-class="::$root.icons.basket"></span>
    <currency value="project.project.total.total" class="price-total ng-isolate-scope ng-hide" ng-show="!session.hidePrice &amp;&amp; project.project.pricing">
      <span class="currency ng-binding">
        <span ng-class="left" class="ng-binding currency-sign-left">£</span>
        1,089.02
        <span ng-class="right" class="ng-binding ng-hide">£</span>
      </span>
    </currency>
    <span ng-show="session.hidePrice || !project.project.pricing" class="ng-binding">
        CHANGE ME
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla possible solution:

To replace a string you can use `String.prototype.replace()`.

If you need instead to append some text in innerHTML you can use `+-` (JavaScript Assignment Operator) which will append your new content in the current content visible in `innerHTML`;

```
myClasses[i].innerHTML += "new content";
```

Generic example using Assignment Operator:

```js
let result = document.getElementById('result');
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', event => {
   result.innerHTML += 'new content</br>';
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me!</button>
<div id="result">Hello some content here!</br></div>
```

Comment: The questioner wants to replace the words 'change me'.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to only look at text content, then you should iterate over all the text nodes and apply a test/replace on each of those. You can use `createTreeWalker` to iterate over such nodes:

```js
function textNodesUnder(el){
  var n, a=[], walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
  while(n=walk.nextNode()) a.push(n);
  return a;
}

textNodesUnder(document.querySelector('.price')).forEach(function(node) {
  node.data = node.data.replace('CHANGE ME', 'new Content');
});
```

```html
<div class="price">

<a class="button" ng-click="commands.order.execute()" ng-class="(!session.hidePrice &amp;&amp; project.project.requiredCalculation) ? 'refreshing' : ''">
    <span class="icon mdi mdi-cart" ng-class="::$root.icons.basket"></span>
    <currency value="project.project.total.total" class="price-total ng-isolate-scope ng-hide" ng-show="!session.hidePrice &amp;&amp; project.project.pricing"><span class="currency ng-binding"><span ng-class="left" class="ng-binding currency-sign-left">£</span>1,089.02<span ng-class="right" class="ng-binding ng-hide">£</span></span></currency>

    <span ng-show="session.hidePrice || !project.project.pricing" class="ng-binding">
        CHANGE ME
    </span>
</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not using angularjs with `ng-bind`:

```
<span ng-show="session.hidePrice || !project.project.pricing"
   ng-bind="(session.hidePrice || !project.project.pricing) ? 'CHANGE ME' : 'new Content'" 
   class="ng-binding">    
</span>
```

Using a directive:

```
app.directive('price', function(){
   return {
     restrict:'C',
     link:function(scope, el, attrs){
        angular.element(el).find('span').last().html('new Content');
     }
  };
})
```

Comment: yes, that would be the best solution, but the OP says they don't have access to the source code, they can only inject JS

Comment: I cant edit the html (only append further html to the bottom)

Comment: _I can append extra code to the end._...so i guess this is html. @James

Comment: Yes but only at the end of the document (before the /body)

Comment: hmmm... what about writing a directive for the `.price`